# Is static content ever stored in the di / generated folders?

Tags: magento-2.1, static-content, setup-di-compile

I'm doing some theme development, which I am somewhat new to.  I am making changes to some files, and I like to test if they can compile correctly, so I run the setup:static-content:deploy somewhat regularly.

Prior to doing so, I purposely wipe the pub/static folder as well as var/page_cache & view_preprocessed folders respectively. The one thing that I do not know, if static-content is ever deployed into the generation/di folders ?

So if I'm doing compilation testing for .less file changes, do I need at all to wipe di & generation folder and re-run setup:di:compile ?

Just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

´generated' is used for generated code, like factories and interceptors.
´di´ is used to store information regarding dependency injection.

As such, those 2 folders don't affect rendering less files.
´view_preprocessed´ stores concatenated less files, so you well have to delete this one, and ´cache´ and ´page_cache´ affect rendered html, so you only need to flush those if the html is changed or you added a new stylesheet / JavaScript.

However, you're better of setting Magento to developer mode since this will create symbolic links in the ´pub´-folder, minimizing the need for deploying static content.

Comment: I'm actually running in developer mode, but I find testing with cache disabled is stupid slow. So I leave the cache enabled. I just clear it often. In this particular instance, I was attempting to add some css to a themeforest based theme, so I have to do a little poking around to find the correct file that was generating the styles-l.css file.  Some of these themes are very poorly documented.

Comment: As such, I had to force recompilation to make sure I wasn't breaking the existing theme, and to make sure I was putting my changes into the correct file. I have found that the on-the-fly compilation doesn't always pick up changes (not sure why tbh).

Comment: @spyrule  Create a child theme, make your purchased theme its parent, do css changes in there, using page source code as a guide.  You should be able to read the source code since your not in production mode, per your commment on another post.

Comment: @Jason Thank you. Since I wrote this initial question, I have since understood and installed grunt. This takes a lot of the guess work out of this process.  However, I do like the idea of making a child theme from the parent theme to build into.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, those folders (DI and generation) do not contain any frontend assets. As such, I don't think it would be necessary.